# list logic in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i have a list with True False Values,

```
visited =[True, False, True, False]
```

I'm not sure if its possible but id like to use list logic in a while loop when the list is empty or visited has no more False values id like to end the While loop
Here is my try it seem to be a infinite loop. And i'm unable to change False Values when i come across one here is my code

```
class mass:

    def __init__(self):
        visited =[True, False, True, False]
        self.x = 0
        while len([self.x for self.x, values in enumerate(visited) if visited[self.x] == False ]) > 0:
            print(self.x)
            visited[self.x] = True
            print(visited)
            self.x = 0
c = mass()
c
```

Id like to change the false values as well as stop the loop one the length reaches 0 in the while loop. When i do this in python console i get the output

```
>>> [x for x, values in enumerate(visited) if visited[x] == False ]
[1, 3]
visited =[True, True, True, True]
```

Then if i do

```
>>> visited =[True, True, True, True]
>>> [x for x, values in enumerate(visited) if visited[x] == False ]
[]
```

so then i tried

```
>>> print(len([x for x, values in enumerate(visited) if visited[x] == False ]))
0
```

Which lead me to think i can do

```
while  len([x for x, values in enumerate(visited) if visited[x] == False ]) > 0
```

Which loops continuously.
Any advice would  be excellent thank you

Comment: Your intent is not clear. Do you want the while loop to break when there are no `False` values in the list?

Comment: Yes that's what im trying to do But im unable to change the false values. Which is a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you clarified in the comments:

Consider this example:

```
import random
li = [False, False, False]

while not all(li):
    print('here')
    i = random.randint(0, 2)
    li[i] = True
```

This code will print 'here' an arbitary number of times, until all the values of `li` become `True`.

The key in this answer is the condition of the `while` loop, `while not all(li)`.

Comment: I thought about using `all` too, but for a straight solution with no random values I preferred a classic `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems to be overengineered or the problem description is lacking crucial points.

If you just want to set all values to `True` you can do the following.

```
visited = [True, False, True, False]
for index in range(len(visited)):
    visited[index] = True
print(visited)
```

If you only want to change the value if it is not `True` do this:

```
visited = [True, False, True, False]
for index, value in enumerate(visited):
   if not value:    
       visited[index] = True
print(visited)
```